# Connecting node js from Docker container to a Mongo db atlas database

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker, mongodb-atlas

I am trying to learn docker concepts along with node.js and mongodb.I have a node js app running inside docker container.What it solely does is update/upsert document in a mongo db database.
This mongodb database I am using is hosted on Mongodb Atlas.
When I run the node.js using `node index.js`directly in the commandline it works properly.The document gets updated.
However,If I run the docker container as

```
docker run firstdatabase:latest
```

it does not update the database.
I do however get the following response from the database:

```
    D:\nodes\firstDatabase>docker run -it firstdatabase:latest 
database created CommandResult {   result:    { n: 1,
         nModified: 0,
         opTime: { ts: [Object], t: 2 },
         electionId: 7fffffff0000000000000002,
         ok: 1 },   connection:    Connection {
         domain: null,
         _events:
          { error: [Object],
            close: [Object],
            timeout: [Object],
            parseError: [Object] },
         _eventsCount: 4,
         _maxListeners: undefined,
         options:
          { host: 'cluster0-shard-00-01-7srki.mongodb.net',
            port: 27017,
            size: 5,
            minSize: 0,
            connectionTimeout: 30000,
            socketTimeout: 360000,
            keepAlive: true,
            keepAliveInitialDelay: 300000,
            noDelay: true,
            ssl: true,
            checkServerIdentity: true,
            ca: null,
            crl: null,
            cert: null,
            key: null,
            passPhrase: null,
            rejectUnauthorized: false,
            promoteLongs: true,
            promoteValues: true,
            promoteBuffers: false,
            reconnect: false,
            reconnectInterval: 1000,
            reconnectTries: 30,
            domainsEnabled: false,
            disconnectHandler: [Object],
            cursorFactory: [Object],
            emitError: true,
            socketOptions: {},
            setName: 'Cluster0-shard-0',
            promiseLibrary: [Function: Promise],
            clientInfo: [Object],
            authProviders: [Object],
            monitoring: false,
            parent: [Object],
            user: 'xyz',
            password: '****',
            read_preference_tags: null,
            authSource: 'admin',
            readPreference: [Object],
            rs_name: 'Cluster0-shard-0',
            dbName: 'admin',
            servers: [Array],
            auth: [Object],
            server_options: [Object],
            db_options: [Object],
            rs_options: [Object],
            mongos_options: [Object],
            socketTimeoutMS: 360000,
            connectTimeoutMS: 30000,
            bson: BSON {} },
         id: 2,
         logger: Logger { className: 'Connection' },
         bson: BSON {},
         tag: undefined,
         messageHandler: [Function],
         maxBsonMessageSize: 67108864,
         port: 27017,
         host: 'cluster0-shard-00-01-7srki.mongodb.net',
         family: undefined,
         keepAlive: true,
         keepAliveInitialDelay: 300000,
         noDelay: true,
         connectionTimeout: 30000,
         socketTimeout: 360000,
         destroyed: false,
         domainSocket: false,
         singleBufferSerializtion: true,
         serializationFunction: 'toBinUnified',
         ca: null,
         crl: null,
         cert: null,
         key: null,
         passphrase: null,
         ciphers: null,
         ecdhCurve: null,
         ssl: true,
         rejectUnauthorized: false,
         checkServerIdentity: true,
         responseOptions:
          { promoteLongs: true,
            promoteValues: true,
            promoteBuffers: false },
         flushing: false,
         queue: [],
         connection:
          TLSSocket {
            _tlsOptions: [Object],
            _secureEstablished: true,
            _securePending: false,
            _newSessionPending: false,
            _controlReleased: true,
            _SNICallback: null,
            servername: null,
            npnProtocol: undefined,
            alpnProtocol: false,
            authorized: true,
            authorizationError: null,
            encrypted: true,
            _events: [Object],
            _eventsCount: 8,
            connecting: false,
            _hadError: false,
            _handle: [Object],
            _parent: null,
            _host: 'cluster0-shard-00-01-7srki.mongodb.net',
            _readableState: [Object],
            readable: true,
            domain: null,
            _maxListeners: undefined,
            _writableState: [Object],
            writable: true,
            allowHalfOpen: false,
            _bytesDispatched: 981,
            _sockname: null,
            _pendingData: null,
            _pendingEncoding: '',
            server: undefined,
            _server: null,
            ssl: [Object],
            _requestCert: true,
            _rejectUnauthorized: false,
            _idleTimeout: 360000,
            _idleNext: [Object],
            _idlePrev: [Object],
            _idleStart: 4777,
            _destroyed: false,
            read: [Function],
            _consuming: true,
            [Symbol(asyncId)]: 27,
            [Symbol(bytesRead)]: 0,
            [Symbol(asyncId)]: 30,
            [Symbol(triggerAsyncId)]: 11 },
         writeStream: null,
         hashedName: '0de073ba71529deddc76bfe3d186c51c10aed56e',
         workItems: [],
         buffer: null,
         sizeOfMessage: 0,
         bytesRead: 0,
         stubBuffer: null },   message:    Response {
         parsed: true,
         raw: <Buffer 87 00 00 00 b6 40 81 06 0d 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 08 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 63 00 00 00 10 6e 00 01 00 00 00 10 6e 4d ... >,
         data: <Buffer 08 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 63 00 00 00 10 6e 00 01 00 00 00 10 6e 4d 6f 64 69 66 69 65 64 00 00 00 00 00 03 6f 70 54 ... >,
         bson: BSON {},
         opts:
          { promoteLongs: true,
            promoteValues: true,
            promoteBuffers: false },
         length: 135,
         requestId: 109134006,
         responseTo: 13,
         opCode: 1,
         fromCompressed: undefined,
         responseFlags: 8,
         cursorId: Long { _bsontype: 'Long', low_: 0, high_: 0 },
         startingFrom: 0,
         numberReturned: 1,
         documents: [ [Object] ],
         cursorNotFound: false,
         queryFailure: false,
         shardConfigStale: false,
         awaitCapable: true,
         promoteLongs: true,
         promoteValues: true,
         promoteBuffers: false,
         index: 119,
         hashedName: '0de073ba71529deddc76bfe3d186c51c10aed56e' },   modifiedCount: 0,   upsertedId: null,   upsertedCount: 0,   matchedCount: 1 }
```

What could be the reason?

Comment: I am not entirely sure of the log output but by default your containers are not connected to each other and cannot see each other. You have to create a docker network and connect both containers over it. Only then will your containers be able to connect. You were able to connect to atlas because it's on a remote server but your containers are both set locally

Comment: `{ n: 1,   nModified: 0,` Actually tells you that `n: 1` the operation "matched" the document it was asked to, so there's nothing wrong with connections. And `nModified: 0` simply means whatever "change" you think you were issuing actually would not affect the document at all. A common case is doing "multiple" issues of the same `$set` operation. i.e `{ "$set": { "field": 1 } }`. On the first iteration it may actually change the document. But the next time you run it, the value is already `1`, so nothing gets changed.

Comment: If you're really unsure still, then post the `index.js` content which shows how the `.update()` is actually being issued and the values it is supposed to change. But as noted, the response object data seems to indicate that everything already worked exactly how it should. If you expect "modification", then "change the data to a different value" than what you intend to set.

Comment: Well as I have mentioned in the question if I run the index.js directly using the command 'node index.js' it works properly. Now if I run the code through a docker container I get the above result. Of course I am updating /upserting new document. Will post the index.js in a while.

Comment: @omarwaleed the database runs in mongodb Atlas.

Comment: for starters, what is your Docker file?

Comment: Hey folks..thank you for the response..My mistake was i was not rebuilding docker image.Now that i rebuild the docker image.. it is working!Thanks!